# Use MutationObserver for multiple nodes

Tags: javascript, html, mutation-observers, mutation

I have a some elements in my HTML which are dynamically filled with text by an API. Now I want to check, if all elements have a value and then start a function. With the following code I'm able to observe only one element.

As expected for `var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("creationDate");` I get the issue `Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`.

How can I check it for all elements with the class `creationDate` and if they all are not empty, start a function?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rgMatches">
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:10:00
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:23
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:22
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
        2022-09-24 16:05:27
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="GroupItem">
      <div class="creationDate">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var delay = (function() {
var timer = 0;
return function(callback, ms) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

var targets = document.getElementsByClassName("creationDate");
console.log(target);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    alert(targets.innerText);   
});

observer.observe(targets, {
    attributes:    true,
    childList:     true,
    characterData: true
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.observer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) expects a `Node` as its first argument and you are passing it a collection.

Run a loop:

```
[...targets].forEach((target) => {
observer.observe(target, {
    attributes:    true,
    childList:     true,
    characterData: true
});

});
```

Also the way this is written seems to be incorrect:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    alert(targets.innerText);   
});
```

You are not making use of the `mutations` at all. You need to check what type of mutation ocurred and based on that do something.
The first argument is an array of [mutations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord)

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver#examples), you might need something like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
....
if(mutation.type === 'childList'){
console.log(mutation.addedNodes);
}
...
});
});
```

Comment: Shaki Thank you very much for your help. targets is a HTMLCollection and I get an issue 'targets.forEach is not a function'

Comment: My bad. Just make it an array using `Array.from()` or `[...]`

Comment: Can I use this MutationObserver on current nodejs version 18.14.2 LTS, 19.7.0 Current? Any polyfill or package will also do.